# How to check if the first element of each tuple inside a list is a key of a dictionary?

Tags: python

For instance, if there's a dictionary student_gpa where:

```
student_gpa = {'Alex': 3.00, 
               'John': 3.50,
               'Jennifer': 3.75}
```

and a list of tuples student_age where:

```
student_age = [('Mike', 14),
              ('Alex', 13),
              ('John', 15)]
```

How do I check if 'Mike', 'Alex', and 'John'  are all keys inside the dictionary student_gpa?

Answer (score 1):

To check if an object is a key in a `dict` you can use the `in` keyword directly like so:

`name in dict`

Alternatively, `dict.keys()` can be made into an `iterable` of all keys in the `dict` and used similarly

`name in dict.keys()`

However, if you just want to check that all your students exist in the `dict`
you can use `all()` and a list comprehension to determine if all names are found within the list of `keys`.

```
>>> all(student in student_gpa.keys() for student, age in student_age)
#False

>>> student_gpa['Mike'] = 1.0
>>> all(student in student_gpa.keys() for student, age in student_age)
#True
```

Comment: The simpler `name in dict` is shorter and more pythonic

Comment: Also, dict.keys() must be cast to list, as it is a dict_keys object in python3

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the list, checking the first element of each tuple. Then check if that value is a key:

```
for i in student_age:
    if i[0] in student_gpa.keys():
        print("yes")`
```

Using `student_gpa.keys()` returns a view object of the keys in `student_gpa`. A view object is an iterable. [Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-dictionary-keys-method/) is a nice article explaining `.keys()`.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could try using `zip`, and try using a generator with `all`, like below:

```
print(all(i in student_gpa.keys() for i in list(zip(*student_age))[0])
```

Output:

```
False
```

@PacketLoss's answer is good too:

```
print(all(x in student_gpa.keys() for x, y in student_age))
```

Output:

```
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that worked for me

```
tuple_list = [("a", "b"),("c", "d")]
first_tuple_elements = [a_tuple[0] for a_tuple in tuple_list]#Getting all tupples first element
student_gpa = {'a': 3.00, 
               'c': 3.50}
for key in first_tuple_elements:
    if key in list(student_gpa.keys()):
        print(key)
```

Output:

```
a
c
```

To check for if all of the first element of list of tuple are key in the dictionary

```
print(first_tuple_elements in list(student_gpa.keys()))
```

Output:

```
True
```

To check if all the keys of of dic are present in a list of tuple and vice versa

```
print(list(student_gpa.keys())==first_tuple_elements)
```

Output:

```
True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with loop.

```
student_gpa = {'Alex': 3.00,
                   'John': 3.50,
                   'Jennifer': 3.75}
student_age = [('Mike', 14),
                  ('Alex', 13),
                  ('John', 15)]
student_gpa_keys = list(student_gpa.keys())
list_keys = [item[0] for item in student_age]
    
for ele in list_keys:
    if ele in student_gpa_keys:
        print(ele)
```

result:

```
Alex
John
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why some answers are so fixed on using single line code. IMHO, the below is clean and easy to understand, especially for a beginner.

```
for student, age in student_age:
    if student in student_gpa: # no need to use student_gpa.keys() to check if a key exists
        print(student, 'is in the dictionary')
        # Do something
    else:
        print(student, 'is not in the dictionary')
        # Do something else
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using list comprehension.

```
student_gpa = {'Alex': 3.00, 
               'John': 3.50,
               'Jennifer': 3.75}
student_age = [('Mike', 14),
              ('Alex', 13),
              ('John', 15)]

students = [std for std, _ in student_age if std in student_gpa]

print (students)
```